# Executing rest of the script while creating http server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, webserver

My problem is a bit complex. Let's say that I have a function in node.js that prints stuff and listens for user's input. Today I've tried adding an http server that I want to be active while the rest of the script is running (its objective is to print something specific on the site). However, when the server starts the rest of the code doesn't execute and nothing gets printed in my console, altough the http server is running. What can I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: Currently it's hard to tell exactly what are you trying to do, and what's the problem with it. Please insert your [code](/help/reprex) to the question, and read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I know that I should've added my code in the question but it uses a custom library called mineflayer and there isn't just a part of it that rapresents the problem. I'll add another piece of code that's similar to mine in my question.